How to solve code signing problem on new Mac?
I want to sign my application with my Apple codesign certificate on my new Mac laptop, with a: "Developer ID Application: Developer Name (8XXXXXXXXX)"
I downloaded and installed in Keychain Access (in Default Keychains login) all required certificates from my developer.apple.com account. That I generated when worked on my old Mac.
But when I try to do that with:
codesign --force --options=runtime --strict --verify --verbose --sign "Developer ID Application: Developer Name (8XXXXXXXXX)" "/path/to/..."

I get the following error:
error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.

The command:
security find-identity -p codesigning -v

return
0 valid identities found

I dont understand why.

Did you install both the certificate and its private key in the keychain, or only the certificate?

Only certificates.
Hm... If I understand correctly I lost my private key on with my old Mac?
I just found the CSR file: "CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest"
but it is not a private key?

In Keychain Access, select the certificate. At the top of the screen, does it say "This certificate is valid"?

Yes. It valids.

What is the title of the certificate, as shown in Keychain Access?

As I mentioned in my post: "Developer ID Application: Developer Name (8XXXXXXXXX)" Issued by: Developer ID Certification Authority Expires: Wednesday, November 18, 2026 at 3:30:28 PM Western European Standard Time

But If I understand correctly I should to restore the private key for this certificates and add this key to my keychains to might sign my binnaries.
Is it possible to do with CSR file that I used when generate this certs or I should to do all again? (i.e. generate new CSR file and issue new certs)

I think you should read https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/732320 and https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/699268

The CSR does not contain the private key. The private key will generally be stored in the Login keychain on the Mac where you originally created the certificate, and is not exported unless you specifically do something to export it. If you can recover that keychain, you should do so. If you lost the private key certificate, you cannot use that certificate anymore and will need to create a replacement (and this time back up the cert & its private key). See the links @matt suggested.
